# rails where not clause is not returning the records when the column value is null?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, where-clause

iam having the following query.

```
punch_recs = emp.punch_in_outs.where(date: Date.today-14 .. Date.today-1).where.not('status' => "Travel")
```

the above query is working fine as expected, when the `status` column value is not equal to nil. but when the `status` column value is nil then those records i am not getting. whats wrong with this query i am not getting. my requirement is i want to get those records for those records the `date` column value should be with in the menctioned range and the `status` column value should not be "travel".(even if there is no `status` i mean if `status` is null also, i want to get those records.) but this query is not giving the records for those `status` is nill or null.

Comment: whats the `sql` run behind scenes?

Comment: 2.2.2 :082 >   punch_recs = emp.punch_in_outs.where(date: Date.today-14 .. Date.today-1).where.not('status' => "Travel")
  PunchInOut Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `punch_in_outs`.* FROM `punch_in_outs`  WHERE `punch_in_outs`.`employee_id` = 1 AND (`punch_in_outs`.`date` BETWEEN '2015-12-12' AND '2015-12-25') AND (`punch_in_outs`.`status` != 'Travel')

Comment: are you sure about nil values in table for particular user?

Answer (score 2):

`NULL` in SQL is unknown, it is not equal to anything. You need to handle the case separately:

```
punch_recs = emp.punch_in_outs.
  where(date: Date.today-14 .. Date.today-1).
  where("status != 'Travel' OR status IS NULL")
```

Comment: Yup. NULL isn't equal, or *not* equal to anything (including itself.) It's unknown.